# Страницы в Yii Framework

Tags: framework, php, html, css

Привет всем!

Только начал изучать это фреймворк, уже установил на локалке , чуть по чуть читаю , пытаюсь что то сделать , прошу подсказать как создать страницу на подобии Home, About etc, и чтобы появилась в "меню".

P.S За полезные ссылки отдельное спасибо и +сик в карму )

Answer (score 4):

Видеокурсы здесь рекламировать, вроде, не принято. Но, думаю, один раз -- можно))

[Видеокурс программирования на Yii framework](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4172581).

+После этого советую читать Cookbook, на русском вроде тоже он есть.

Comment: да, прикольная штука для начинающих :) поставлю +1

Comment: @Shrek, )))

Answer (score 3):

Для начала прочитайте полностью пример: [Создание блога на Yii](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/blog/ru/start.overview)

> Данное учебное пособие описывает процесс создания блога, показанного в демонстрационном приложении, которое можно найти в архиве с фреймворком. Каждый шаг разработки описан подробно и может быть применён при создании других приложений. В дополнение к полному руководству и API, данное пособие показывает, вместо полного и подробного описания, пример практического применения Yii.

Comment: Подскажите почему Model Generator создал tbl_user , а остальные не создает, не дает пишет undefined.

Comment: за такие ответы к стене ставить надо. эта документация больше путает.

читаю документацию. уже понадеялся что-то человекопонятное увидеть. а тут такое....

Answer (score 3):

> Только начал изучать это фреймворк, уже установил на локалке , чуть по чуть читаю ,

Раз только начал, тогда как написал [[@Zhukov Roman](/users/10590/zhukov-roman)](/users/10590/zhukov-roman) прочитай про создание блога.

> пытаюсь что то сделать

это хорошо, что пытаешься. Но даже для создания страниц нужно понимание MVC и как ты их хочешь сделать, статические или они из БД браться будут.

Тут  напаханное поле действий.

ps о боже я целый месяц проспал, вышел **1.1.13 (Dec 30, 2012) Stable**

Comment: @Shrek Такая же просьба, почему Model Generator создал tbl_user , а остальные не создает, не дает пишет undefined.

Comment: >MVC знаю как выглядит,

Мало знать как выглядит, нужно знать как работает!

А где ты создаешь модели? Через что? через gii?

Comment: @Shrek да через Gii

Comment: значит в бд нет таких таблиц либо ты неправильно вводишь их названия.

Comment: @Shrek А Gii разве не сам должен создавать ? Или я где то что то пропустил ? Таблицы как то по другому создавать надо ? )

Answer (score 0):

[вот](http://loco.ru/materials/177-yii-course-1-3-sozdanie-polzovatelei-prostaya-sistema-avtorizacii)  . очень помогло. сам обучаюсь. уже и аутетнтификацию осилил)))

Comment: ну ты прям Лара Крофт :D